# Convert array to array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like this:

```js
const categories = ["Action", "Comedy", "Thriller", "Drama"]
```

And I would like to convert it to this format:

```js
const displayedCategories = [{"type": "Action", "isDisplayed": true},{"type": "Comedy", "isDisplayed": true},{"type": "Thriller", "isDisplayed": true},{"type": "Drama", "isDisplayed": true}]
```

Any advice ? :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For a future reference check out how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. @AndrewL64 is right, you should provide at least what you have tried, otherwise you're just asking others to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const categories = ["Action", "Comedy", "Thriller", "Drama"];

const newCategories = categories.map(category => ({
  type: category,
  isDisplayed: true
}));

console.log(newCategories);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
const displayedCategories = categories.map(function(category) {
   return { type: category, isDisplayed: true };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like This:

```js
const categories = ["Action", "Comedy", "Thriller", "Drama"];
var out = [];
for(var key in categories){
  out.push({"type": categories[key], "isDisplayed": true});
}
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

use array.prototype.map to convert the array into an object

```
categories = catergories.map(val => {
  var obj =  {
    type:val
    //more properties go here
  }
  return obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const categories = ["Action", "Comedy", "Thriller", "Drama"]
const displayedCategories = categories.map(category =>  { return {"type": category, "isDisplayed": true} })
console.log('displayedCategories :', displayedCategories);
```